# Column chooser not shown up on the page for jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to use the datatable column chooser as shown in [Datatable Colvis](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/index.html) as shown below

```
$('#tableId').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oColVis": {
                "aiExclude": [ 0,15 ]
               },

    "aaSorting": [],
    "aaData":[],
    "aoColumns": [],
    "bScrollInfinite": true,
    "sScrollY": "280px",
    "sScrollX": "963px",
    "bDestroy":true,
    "iDisplayLength" : 10,
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
        // custom scroll bars
        //$('#tableId').find('.dataTables_scrollBody').jScrollPane();
    },
});
```

I have added 16 columns which I cant show up in the code here.
But the column chooser doesn't show up on the UI. Any mistake am doing here?

Comment: any errors on console..?

Comment: @sasi No error on console

Comment: could you post your html as well?

Comment: <table  id="tableId"></table>

Comment: Am adding the columns to table inside "aoColumns": []

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I had not added ColVis plugin JS to application, so it was not working. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just spent the past hour trying to figure out why it wasn't working. I thought ColVis was builtin, I thought wrong. Thanks for the tip.